# Rails alias for attributes on polymorphic association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I have a rails application where there are multiple types of users using a polymorphic association, like this:

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true
 has_many :posts
end
```

Player:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile
end
```

Coach:

```
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile
```

end

The schemas for these tables, let's say,are as follows:

```
User(userId: integer, username: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, profile_id: integer, profile_type: string)

Player(playerId: integer, playerName: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Coach(coachId: integer, coachName: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Post(postId: integer, userId: integer, content: string ...)
```

Player and Coaches can write posts, which will be added to the Database with their userId. This is easy enough, but now I want a query that returns all posts, together with the name of the Player or Coach who wrote it. Or query Users based on these same name fields, to be able to do a name search and get userId.

Since the name columns have different titles, I can't just do `User.profile.name`, nor do I know any decent way to query Users based on the content of its "child" tables. I don't want to have to check the profile_type each time and then look for a different thing depending on it. Is it possible to give these field an alias or something? What can I do to get their fields regardless of type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into [`alias_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute).

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :name, :column_name
end
```

Comment: This seems really useful, thank. But can If I name `coachName` and `playerName` with the same Alias, can I query by the alias and it'll treat them the same? How can I use it to look for something like 'give me all users whose profile.name = "xx"  '?

Comment: I guess it was good enough, eventually got result I wanted. Accepting answer, thanks!